# Strong Induction Proof: Every natural number = sum of distinct powers of 2

Tags: induction

The question I'm looking at, is to show that every positive integer $n$ can be written as a sum of distinct powers of two.

I can see that you can form any number based on the highest $2^t$ that is less than the number, plus some combination of $2^j<n$'s. And that you can make the number odd, by adding $2^0$ at the end.

I just don't know how to create the formula for the proof. I'm trying to figure out my base case, and then my inductive formula to figure out $k+1$, and I've got nothing.

Comment: You'll need to separately consider the cases where $k+1$ is odd and even. The former is trivial. You really only use induction for the latter. What can you say about $\frac{k+1}{2}$ in this case?

Comment: It seems to me that what you want to prove is that, for each integer $m$, that all the integers from $2^m$ to $2^{m+1}-1$ can be written as the sum of distinct power of 2. This can be readily (he says without proof) proved by induction.

Comment: @RickDecker, I'm a bit confused here. Does your edit contain an extra statement: "And that you can make the number odd, by adding $2^0$ at the end."?

Comment: @J.D. Okay, now I'm doubly confused. Let me try once more. (My initial comment, a few hours ago, was): The sentence in question was part of the original post, despite the fact that it appears nowhere in the edit history. (My current comment is) My initial comment has vanished.

I'm leaving this thread forever; it's making me doubt my sanity and at my age that's a very bad thing.

Comment: If P(k) is even then the answer should be obvious. If P(k) is odd, then $m = \dfrac{P(k)+1}{2}$ can be expressed as the sum of powers of $2$ and P(k+1) = 2m + 1.

Comment: The trick is that you aren't doing the usual induction on P(n) => P(n+1) but on P(k; k < 2^n) => P(2^n + k).

Comment: Don't do induction on $n$.  Do induction on $t$.  the proposition isn't P(n) = "n can be written as a sum".  It's P(t) = "Every n < 2^t can be written as a sum".

Answer (score 14):

The statement is obviously true for $n=0$.

Assume that we are given an $n\geq1$ and that it is true for all $m$ with $0\leq m<n$.

When $n=2m$ then $m<n$ and therefore $m=\sum_k 2^{p_k}$ with finitely many $p_k$, all of them different. It follows that $n=\sum_k 2^{p_k+1}$ with all $p_k+1$ different.

When $n=2m+1$ with an $m$ as before then $n=2^0+\sum_k 2^{p_k+1}$ with all $p_k+1$ different and different from $0$.

Comment: When $n=2m+1$, why $n=2^0+\sum_k 2^{p_k+1}$?

Comment: @Dhruv: Multiplying by $2$ raises the exponent by $1$.

Comment: Sorry, I got it.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps people will find this method easier...

$Proof$. We will use strong induction to prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ we can express $n$ as a sum of distinct powers of $2$.

*Base Case.* For $n=1$ note that $2^0=1$ and thus for $n=1$ our proposition holds.

*Inductive Hypothesis.* Assume $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ with $1\le m \le k$ and that our proposition holds for $m$.

*Inductive Step.* We consider two cases.

Case 1. If $k+1$ is even then observe that $\frac{k+1}{2}$ must be an integer. Now since $1\le \frac{k+1}{2} \le k$ we know by our inductive hypothesis that $\frac{k+1}{2}$ is the sum of distinct powers of $2$. But then multiplying $\frac{k+1}{2}$ by $2$ gives

$$\frac{k+1}{2}\cdot2=k+1$$

and since (by the distributive property of multiplication over addition) each distinct power of $2$ in the sum $\frac{k+1}{2}$ is multiplied by a factor of $2$, each power of $2$ is increased by $1$ and thus remains distinct.

*Case 2.* If $k+1$ is odd then we know $k$ is even. Furthermore we know by our inductive hypothesis that $k$ may expressed as the sum of distinct powers of $2$. But if $k$ is even we know $k$ does not contain a $2^0=1$ in its sum of distinct powers of $2$.

**Remark:** To observe that $2^0=1$ does not exist in the sum of distinct powers of $2$ that makeup $k$, note that $k$, by the definition of an even integer, may be expressed as $2m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ (since $k$ is positive we limit $m$ to the positive integers) and since we can view multiplication as repeated addition we have $2m = 2 + 2 + \cdots + 2 + 2$ where we are taking the sum of $m$ twos. If the sum were to contain a $2^0=1$ we clearly would need to express our integer as $2m+1$ which would make it odd not even.

Thus we see that

$$k+1=k + 2^0$$

and if $k+1$ is odd we may express $k+1$ as the sum of distinct powers of $2$.

It follows by strong mathematical induction that $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ we can express $n$ as a sum of distinct powers of $2$. $\Box$

Answer (score 5):

Finding such a representation is equivalent to expressing $n$ in binary. We can do induction as follows: Let $2^h$ be the highest power of $2$ less than or equal to $n.$ Then we must have $n-2^{h}< 2^{h+1} - 2^{h}=2^{h}(2-1)=2^{h}.$ Hence the greatest power, say $2^{g},$ of $2$ such that $2^{g}\le n-2^{h}$ must satisfy $g<h.$ By strong induction on $h$ we can assume that $n-2^{h} = \sum_{i=0}^{h-1}c_i2^i$ where each $c_i$ is either $0$ or $1.$ But then we're done, since  this implies $n= \sum_{i=0}^{h-1}c_i2^i + 2^h$ is a sum of distinct powers of $2.$

To be explicit, let's include the induction hypothesis. Namely, for $h=0$ every positive $n\le 2^h=2^0=1$ can be expressed as a power of $2,$ since the only possibility is $1=2^0.$ Thus, we assume that for a given $h>0$ and any $n\le2^h,$ that such a representation exists.

Comment: We know how to express each and every positive integer(n) in any positive integer base(b).

In that case $n=\sum_{0≤r} a_rb^r\ where\ 0≤a_r<b$. If b=2, $n=\sum_{0≤r} a_r2^r\ where\ 0≤a_r<2 =>here\ a_r=0,1$. Clearly, every positive integer is the sum of distinct powers of 2.  Why induction is at all required?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I merely tried to give a proof of this fact, as it seemed to be the OP's goal to prove it using induction. I'm not sure whether there can be a proof without induction.

Answer (score 1):

*Not an inductive proof, but I thought I'll add it anyway.*

---

$\require{cancel} $
Consider the generating function

$$\prod_{k = 1}^\infty (1 + x^{2^k}) = (1 + x)(1 + x^2)(1 + x^4)(1 + x^8)... \tag{1}$$

In $(1)$, $(1 + x^{2^k})$ can be interpreted as saying that $2^k$ can be either used zero times or one time in a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence, the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of the product finds all partitions of $n$ consisting of only distinct powers of $2$.

Note from $a + b = \frac{a^2 - b^2}{a - b}$ that

$$1 + x^{2^k} = \frac{1 - x^{2^{k + 1}}}{1 - x^{2^k}}$$

Hence, we can rewrite $(1)$ as follows:

$$(1) = \frac{\cancel{1 - x^2}}{1 - x} \cdot \frac{\cancel{1 - x^4}}{\cancel{1 - x^2}} \cdot \frac{\cancel{1 - x^8}}{\cancel{1 - x^4}} \cdot ... = \frac{1}{1 - x} \tag{2}$$

We know, from geometric series, that
$$(2) = \frac{1}{1 - x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + \; ... \tag{3}$$
$$\implies (1) = (3)$$

Note that the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(3)$ can also be interpreted to denote the number of partitions of $n$ subject to some conditions.

From $(1) = (3)$ and their combinatorial interpretations, we can deduce that every natural number can be represented by the sum of distinct powers of $2$.

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically, since all the numbers up to 2^X can be represented by powers of 2, that makes it 2^X*2-1, which is 1 less than 2^X*2, etc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The subtle thing is the exact wording of the proposition.

If you want to prove:

$P(n) = $ $n$ can be expressed as a distinct sum of powers of $2$.

Initial case: $n = 1$ $P(1)$ is provable.

Induction step: $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$

then this is impossible.  $P(k) \not \implies P(k+1)$ and there is simply no way to show it does.

But if instead you try to prove.

$Q(n) = $ of all $j;  0 < j < 2^n$, $j $ can be written as a distinct product of powers of $2$

then $Q(k) \implies Q(k+1)$ is pretty easy to prove.

(if $0 < j \le 2^{n+1}$ then either $j = m$ or $j = m + 2^n$ where $0 < m < 2^n$ so $m$ can be distinctly written as $\sum 2^i$.  As $m < 2^n$ none of its powers of $2$ are to the $n$ power.  So  $m + 2^n = 2^n + \sum 2^i $ is a sum with distinct powers of $2$.  So $j$, whethe $j = m$ or $j = m + 2^n$ can be written as a sum of distinct powers.)

...

Another way to view this, albeit, maybe not as rigorous.  Is that induction need not be a direct $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ progression.  And $P(n) \implies P(f(n))$ where $\cup_{i \in \mathbb N} F_i= \mathbb N$ where $F_0 = \{1\text{ or } 0\}$ and $F_{i+1} = \{f(a)|a \in \cup_{k \le i}F_i\}$, qualifies as induction as well.

Here $f(n) = n + 2^k$ where $k$ is the smallest power where $2^k > n$.

(although the bit $\cup_{i \in \mathbb N} F_i= \mathbb N$ most likely will boil down to a $Q(n) \implies Q(n+1)$.  e.g.  How do we know $\{0,1\}, \{0,1, 2, 3\},\{0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7\} ....$ will span $\mathbb N$?  Probably by induction.)